# Symfony doctrine bulk insert

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am trying to optimize my doctrine save with bulk insert. But during the save i get the following error:

> A new entity was found through the relationship
>   'AppBundle\Entity\Product#category' that was not configured to cascade
>   persist operations for entity:
>   AppBundle\Entity\Category@00000000351492f00000000072328419. To solve
>   this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this
>   unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the
>   mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). If you cannot
>   find out which entity causes the problem implement
>   'AppBundle\Entity\Category#__toString()' to get a clue.

**My Category Entity:**

```
class Category
{

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=false, unique=true)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var Category
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Category", inversedBy="children")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     */
    private $parent;

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Category", mappedBy="parent", fetch="EAGER")
     */
    private $children;

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection;
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Product", mappedBy="category", fetch="EAGER")
     */
    private $products;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=false)
     */
    private $title;
}
```

**My Product Entity:**

```
class Product
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Category", inversedBy="products")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $category;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer",nullable=true)
    */
    private $stock;

}
```

**My save method:**

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$batchCount = 10;
for ($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++) {
     $product = new Product();
     $product->setName("Product A");
     $product->setCategory("category A");
     $em->persist($product);
     if (($i % $batchCount) == 0) {
         $em->flush();
         $em->clear();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First in your code:

```
$product->setCategory("category A");
```

You couldn't have this because it should require object, but i will assume you have simplified your code for sake of question.

Your problem is that you add association to product, but you don't add association to your category entity.

This has generally two solutions:

```
// In your Product entity add cascade persist, this will check your categories as well and schedule them for persist during flush
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Category", inversedBy="products", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
 */
protected $category;
```

Next solution (I prefer this one, because you have all the time control around everything).

```
// In your product entity set Category
public function setCategory(Category $category) {
    $this->category = $category;
    $category->addProduct($this);
}

// In you Category entity
public function addProduct(Product $product) {
    if (!$this->products->contains($product)) {
        $this->product->add($product);
    }
}
```

You can use both at the same time as well.

Comment: @m-kebza getting this error: "Attempted to call an undefined method named "contain" of class "Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection".
Did you mean to call e.g. "contains" or "containsKey"?
"

Comment: Ah sorry, should be really contains. Fixed.

Comment: @m-kebza i tried this but still the same problem :( –. Even with the cascade persist i still get the same issue.

Comment: For texting purposes, try to remove `clear()` call from your bulk insert. Where could be problem - If you call clear it detaches all entities. So if you used category before and now you try to assign that category again, means that one is already in detached stated.

Comment: @M-kebza if i remove clear() it works but then it does not save all entity in bulk right ? or does it.

Comment: Saving entities happens at `flush()` method call. `clear()` detaches all entities from Doctrine. So thats where you problem happens. If you use clear you need later on load your category entities again so doctrine knows about them.

Instead of `clear()` you should call `$em->detach($product)` for each product after you have flushed them.

Comment: @M-kebza but should this also not insert 10 record per batch ? When i check the database it will save 1 by 1 from what i can see.

Comment: Yes, internally all operations in doctrine are managed though `UnitOfWork` which will do save one entity at the time. The thing is batch here is considered that you are not saving 10000 entities at one time, but only 20 at time, which is much faster.

Comment: @M-kebza so its still doing batches of 20 records ?

Comment: Yes it does. Inserts 20 records (but one by one), processing and then again insert 20 records